# $_GET['id'] not taking id from php url

Tags: php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("meetings");

$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['meeting_cost']) && !empty($_POST['meeting_cost'])){
    // do your database operations here
    echo "Success.";
    $cost = mysql_escape_string($_POST['meeting_cost']);
    echo "<br>" . "<br>" . "Cost is " . $cost . ".";
    mysql_query("UPDATE `meeting_info` SET cost='$cost' WHERE meeting_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
}else{
    echo "[Failed to retrieve meeting cost.]";
}
//echo "Okay, cost is " . $_POST['working'] . ".";


?>
```

I'm just beginning to learn, so bear with me.
So, my url ends like so: `index.php?id=3`, but my `$_GET['id'];` line doesn't actually get the id. Instead, I keep getting the error `undefined index: id`. I've tried changing it to `_POST` and `_REQUEST`, but neither of those work.
What gives? This code has worked for me in the past, but for some reason is not working now.

edit:

```
error message: "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\MeetingCost2\Calculator\process_form.php on line 6"
```

full url: http://localhost/MeetingCost2/Calculator/index.php?id=3

Comment: What do you get when you run print_r($_GET); ?

Comment: paste your full code along with your URL and with complete error message

Comment: I am not able to see line 21 in your code

Comment: Another oops on my part... i removed the style, so line 21 is `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Why do you expect 'id' key to be in $_GET global var if it's POST request?

Comment: If you make POST request you do not have anything in $_GET var. And vice versa. Try to dump both GET and POST array by printing var_dump() of $_REQUEST array before any if statement.

Comment: As long as im being honest, it's because i don't really know what i'm doing.. I'm taking a php class in community college, and it's far past the drop date, so i just need to get through this class, But anyway, this method worked in a previous assignment i had, so i'm pretty confused as to why it wouldn't work now

Comment: @JoshuaHerron Why not passing the same id variable with $_POST?

Comment: @JoshuaHerron Post your html code